# Пролистывание слайдов в Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Каким образом сделать, чтобы в компоненте Bootstrap Carousel при просмотре с мобильных девайсов, можно было пролистывать слайды пальцем? Т.е. не нажимать на контрол.

Comment: поставить обработчик на свайп по таргету и в зависимости от направления листать методами карусель прев или карусель некст

Comment: Спасибо! По запросу "bootstrap carousel on swipe" сразу нашелся рабочий пример https://codepen.io/andrearufo/pen/rVWpyE

Comment: лучшее спасибо - отметьте ответом, поставьте плюс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349984/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-slider-use-mobile-left-right-swipe) есть несколько вариантов решений. Например вот так:

```
 $(".carousel").on("touchstart", function(event){
         var xClick = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
     $(this).one("touchmove", function(event){
         var xMove = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
         if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) > 5 ){
             $(this).carousel('next');
         }
         else if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) < -5 ){
             $(this).carousel('prev');
         }
     });
     $(".carousel").on("touchend", function(){
             $(this).off("touchmove");
     });
 });
```